# an audio device with an OSS driver in modern Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, pulseaudio, oss

My audio device has no driver in Linux.

There's an OSS driver for it, [MMUSBAUDIO](http://www.michaelminn.com/linux/mmusbaudio/).

MMUSBAUDIO provides an OSS driver.

It seems to work. When I `cat foo.wav > /dev/sdp` I get expected audio output from the card.

Is there a way to use this in an integrated form with PulseAudio?

I was thinking, some kind of wrapper around OSS that makes it into a sink for PulseAudio (I hope that this is correct use of the term sink).